# libvirt KVM virtualhost cannot ping router address

Tags: debian, networking, virtual-machine, libvirt

I have a server with ip `192.168.2.101` which hosts a KVM running Debian 10. The host also runs Debian 10. The KVM is networked with virt-manager to a network with ip address space `192.168.30.0/24`, the host has ip `192.168.30.1` and the KVM virtual machine has address `192.168.30.9`.

If I log into the virtual machine I can ping the address `192.168.2.101`, but not the next hop in the chain to the internet, which should be the address of a router, `192.168.2.254`.

I also cannot ping other hosts on the network `192.168.2.0/24`.

The machine `192.168.2.101` has ip forwarding enabled.

Using `tcpdump` I see that ping requests to `192.168.2.254` reach this device, but it doesn't know the ARP address of `192.168.30.9`, and it sends out messages like:

```
xxx ARP, Request who-has 192.168.30.9 tell 192.168.2.254`, length 28
```

Why is this happening? What should I try next to diagnose or fix the issue?

The virtual network is set up as "routed". I can't change it to NAT because I want other machines to have direct access to this virtual host.

Answer (score 2):

Did you do any other network config to get 'routed' mode to work? It doesn't work out of the box. Dan's post here has more details and is still relevant: https://www.berrange.com/posts/2009/12/13/routed-subnets-without-nat-for-libvirt-managed-virtual-machines-in-fedora/

Comment: I managed to fix this issue after I removed the router `192.168.2.254` from the chain. I sent traffic to a different router further down the network chain and set a static route on that router as this link describes. There should have been a static route on the previous router which I removed, but possibly it was not working for some reason?